# Axios request works from componets but not in Pinia Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, pinia

I am making an Axios Request to the server to get the list of the collections from a database. I want to store it in a store so that components can access them globally.

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

export const useAdminDashboardStore = defineStore('useAdminDashboardStore', () => {
  const collectionArr = []
  const getCollectionsNames = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('works from async!')
      const response = await axios.get('/getDBList')
      console.log('after response')
    } catch {
      console.log('not store works')
    }
  }

  return { getCollectionsNames }
})
```

in postman after the get request:

```
"data": [
    "Fundamentals",
    "AsyncJS"
]
```

but If i connect to a store and call the function, i get in console:

```
works from async!
```

And it stops. No console logs after the axios call.

So i copied this code and put it directly in the component:

```
const getCollectionsNames = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('works from async!')
    const response = await axios.get('/getDBList')
    console.log(response.data)
    console.log('after response')
  } catch {
    console.log('not store works')
  }
}

function getFormData() {
  updateCorrectAnswerText()
  getCollectionsNames()
```

and the console now is:

```
works from async!
{data: Array(2)}data: (2) ['Fundamentals', 'AsyncJS'][[Prototype]]: Object
after response
```

and it works. Why doesn't it work in the Pinia store but in component it does? How to fix it?

Comment: out of interest, what if you use `fetch` instead of `axios`

Comment: There's no explanation. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. It could be Axios interceptor on your side or something else. A console isn't a proper way to debug. Whatever happens with the request should be visible in devtools in network tab

Comment: You can check axios inspectors and add a breakpoint to see what's wrong

Comment: The provided example works correctly on my machine (as expected, all logs are shown).